# Utilities to show keyboard blocking?

Tags: windows, linux, keyboard, controller

Quoting from the Wikipedia article, **[Rollover (key)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_%28key%29#Key_blocking_and_ghosting)**:

> Modern keyboards detect ghosting and instead of registering a fourth
>   key will ignore the third key, which is known as blocking.

Are there utilities that run on a PC and that allow me to check if the keyboard is using blocking to prevent ghosting? (I am using a ThinkPad keyboard.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key blocking can be seen quite easily in Windows XP, and possibly even without OS. Example, using the German keyboard on a [Thinkpad T41](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ThinkPad_T_Series):

1. **Hold E**
2. **Hold R**

   Result: `r` is repeatedly printed on screen.
3. **Hold T**

   Result: Windows will stop repeating `r`; instead, it will beep. Likely explanation: Otherwise the keyboard controller can not distinguish between **E** and **R** ([ghosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)#Key_blocking_and_ghosting)).
4. **Release T**
5. **Hold W**

   Result: This time, the character is displayed without problem, showing a `w` repeating on screen.